# Google spreadsheet counta COUNTIFS

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working at Google Spreadsheet and i'm trieing do this:

```
    A    |     B       |     C      |   D
    1    |     ...     |    11      |  (???)
    2    |     ...     |    10      |
    3    |    ....     |    11      |
    4    |   ......    |    11      |
```

(???) D1  = counta unique values at Column A only if Column C = 11.

D1 = 3.

Can anybody help me?

I tested this =COUNTIFS(C:C,"11",A:A,">0") but its sum all "A" (result 10)...

Answer (score 0):

=COUNTA(C:C,"11",A:A,">0") = 10

=COUNTIFS(C:C,"11",A:A,">0") = 3

Typo?

Comment: Hi irozak, the countifs works. But i have a new criteria. The column A can have repeated numbers. Like twice "1". I wanna it sum only once time the number 1. Can you understand? (sorry for the english).

Comment: In your example above, if we change the value in A4 from "4" to "1", what do you want the answer in D1 to be?